# Rails - special validation case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm building a Rails application, where I have following entities: user, place and review. I want to allow each user to add only one review for a one place. I wonder what is the best place to put this validation - to the controller or to models?

This is how it looks like now:

Review (model):

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  ...
```

Place (model):

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  ...
```

User (model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  ...
```

ReviewsController:

```
def create
  @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])

  existing_reviews_count = Review.where(:place_id => @place.id).where(:user_id => current_user.id).count
  if existing_reviews_count == 0
    review = @place.reviews.create(review_params)
    review.user = current_user
    review.save

  # OK
   else
  # BAD
  end

@reviews = Review.all
end
```

I think it would be better to place the validation to the models. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using following validation in Review

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  validates :place_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}
  ...
```

Additionally you can a database index with uniqueness constrain on user_id and place_id in reviews table.